# Is there a way to make an app executable only by the system on android?

Tags: permissions, root-access

I'm trying to make an app executable only by the system or by root on android so that when the user tries to open it (for example, by tapping it) he gets permission denied. Is this possible on a rooted android device?

Comment: Do you have an app which you want to modify for your goal or do you want to develop one? Latter is off-topic here.